# facebook api v 1.0 asking for approve permission user_likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Logon Dialog show warning message

> The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: user_likes.
>   Submit them for review or learn more.

But according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_0) it shouldn't, because my app created before April 30th, 2014.

Link to app: https://www.facebook.com/brights.com.ua/app_327215967365892

Js code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: FB_APP_ID,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
};
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));

function facebookLogon(callback, callbackCancel) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            callback(response.authResponse.accessToken);
        } else {
            if (callbackCancel) {
                callbackCancel();
            }
        }
    }, { scope: FB_PERMISSIONS, privacy: "{ 'value': 'EVERYONE' }" });
};
```

Comment: According to the changelog for v2.0, "Apps that were inactive or have a creation date on or after April 30th, 2014 will not be able to make calls to v1.0 of the API. They must use v2.0." It is very likely that your app has been migrated to v2.0 due to low activity/inactivity. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Your app was inactive before 4/30/2014 so we migrated it to v2.0